# Get value if all objects in chain exist, get fallback value if not

Tags: javascript

Feel kind of stupid to ask..
I want to get something like this:

```
var value = $scope.settings.paper.font.color || 0;
```

The problem is that some of the middle objects may not exist.

Is there an ultimate way to get **value** if all "object chain" exists and get some fallback if not?

For example, in line above if all objects exists, we may return value of **color**, but if only $scope.settings exists, and there's no *paper* object in it, i will get an error, not 0.

Comment: In this chain, color won't exists if settings doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: There is no builtin function for it.

### Shortest generic solution

Simply wrap it into a `try` - `catch`

```
try {
   // handles defaultVal if d is undefined
   yourVar = typeof a.b.c.d === 'undefined' ? defaultVal:a.b.c.d;
} catch (e) {
   // handles defaultVal if a,b or c are undefined
   yourVar = defaultVal;
}
```

### Alternative solution

You could use the following function to safely traverse an object (`gv` - for `getValue`):

```
var gv = function(scope, chainStr, defaultValue) {
    var chain = chainStr.split('.');
    for (var i = 0; i < chain.length; i++) {
        var newScope = scope[chain[i]];
        if (typeof newScope !== 'undefined') {
            scope = newScope;
        } else {
            return defaultValue;
        }
    };
    return newScope;
};
```

Like this:

```
var a = {b:{c:{d:3}}};

console.log(gv(window, 'a.b.c.d', -1));
// 3
console.log(gv(window, 'a.b.c.e', -1));
// -1 
console.log(gv(a, 'b.c.d', -1));
// 3
console.log(gv(a, 'b.c.e', -1));
// -1
```

Comment: try and catch seems to work perfectly. Any suggestions when it may not?

Comment: Not really. But wrote it secondly because it popped later into my mind . Updated answer as well.

Comment: `There is no builtin function for it.`, not really. There is `$parse` service.

Comment: @dfsq: `$parse` is not "built in" - it's part of Angular (and possibly other libraries?)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just check for the existence of $scope and each property in its namespace:

```
var value = (typeof $scope != 'undefined' && $scope.settings && $scope.settings.paper && $scope.settings.paper.font && $scope.settings.paper.font.color) || 0;
```

The last part of the statement in parenthesis will return the value of .font

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/silkster/gM8uh/

Comment: that is not an ultimate solution, of course I can check each element.

Comment: @Quest The only alternative is to wrap the assignment in a try/catch, and set fallback if catch is reached.

Comment: @Quest, I've used a function that given a namespace as a string, will ensure that the each name in the chain exists.  It consists of string splitting and parsing of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of build in `$parse` service:

```
var value = $parse('settings.paper.font.color || 0')($scope);
```

It will make all necessary checks behind the scene.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/1GLb5PEvxMzPMYc5ZxZn?p=preview